# Weekday backup for /home and /etc

Tags: backup

I need to create an automatic backup in Ubuntu that runs from Monday to Friday at 1 am, backuping `/home` and `/etc` in another disk.

Do you know how could I do that?

Answer (score 2):

If your PC runs all the time you can try (as root)

```
crontab -e
```

to start the cron editor. Cron is a service that executes a script at a configured time or after a time intervall has ended.

Now add a line similar to

```
# m h dom mon dow    command
  0 1   *   *  0      /root/mybackupscript.sh 2> /dev/null
```

Then create the /root/mybackupscript.sh:

```
#/bin/sh
# Very simple backup script
rsync -va /home /etc /media/<user>/anotherdisk
```

That's it principially. I do not know where your "another disk" is mounted into the directory tree so please modify it to your needs.

cron and rsync is also a very powerful and flexible tools, so don't forget to read the man pages:

```
man crontab
man rsync
```